# Plotly : is it possible to hide some buttons in the floating toolbar?

Tags: plotly

Generating charts based on Google Charts and Plotly using the XPlot Plotly F# library, I was wondering if it is possible to hide some of the buttons in the floating toolbar that allow to pan, zoom, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know in Python that you can do so with the following command:

```py
# from docs: https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/#removing-modebar-buttons

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[1, 3, 1]))

fig.show(config={
    'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['toggleSpikelines','hoverCompareCartesian']
})
```

But when I look at the code for [Plotly.Net's Config Code](https://github.com/plotly/Plotly.NET/blob/99fb173b7669074f2bec89ae892df60ef4e8cbea/src/Plotly.NET/Config.fs#L391), it doesn't look like that variable is built in yet.

Comment: I see modeBarButtonsToRemove in there. What is it that you think missing?

Comment: I must have missed that in the F# implementation. That argument should be what you use.